# Filter clusters in PostGIS by size

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering

I am clustering points in a table based on their Mercator distance (~10km, it doesn't have to be that precise, so I'm fine with projection distortion). What I want to achieve is to only query the clusters which contain multiple points.

I have come up with this query:

```
select * from 
(SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(ST_Transform(geom, 3857), 10000)) gc
FROM mils) f 
where ST_NumGeometries(gc) > 1;
```

Which does exactly what I want. However, this will do the clustering first on the whole table, and only then filter on the results.

My question is: is this effective enough / the way it should be done, or is there a more efficient way of filtering clusters on the fly?

Please note that the table is not that big, its size is usually between 500 and 10000, tops. Also, I have added a spatial index on the column **geom**.

Comment: I think you are doing the best way possible, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause), can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tables of those sizes it won't matter much, but you should use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` instead, using the *minpoint* parameter to control clustering; as a window function, it should also be faster and can be used to cluster by multiple attributes (specify in the `... OVER(PARTITION BY ...) ...` clause).

```
SELECT *,
       ST_ClusterDBSCAN(ST_Transform(geom, <srid>), 10000, 2) OVER() AS clst_id
FROM mils;
```

will assign `clst_id`s as a new column while keeping the original table structure. Set the *minpoint* parameter accordingly to only create clusters (and assign *ids* only to those points, all others will be assigned *NULL*) with that minimum point density (2 in above example, suiting your request). Note that I left out the SRID; don't use WebMercator for anything distance related, project to the correct UTM Zone or an other suitable projection that fits your area.